# How to return Map as result from named nativ query in xml using JpaRepository

Tags: sql, spring, jpa, named-query

I need to query some count per day and i would like to create named native query that will return this in map. How can i do that ?

```
<named-native-query name="getLeadNumberByDayInDateRange" result-set-mapping="map">
            <query>
                SELECT addeddate, 
                       Count(DISTINCT campaignid, email) AS count 
                FROM   leads 
                GROUP  BY addeddate   
            </query>
        </named-native-query>
```

So i am writing query in xml and i would like to add this into JpaRepository :

```
@Query
public Map<LocalDateTime, Integer> getLeadNumberByDayInDateRange();
```

Answer (score 2):

To do that with named queries one can do something like:

```
@Query("SELECT l.addeddate, Count(DISTINCT l.campaignid)
        FROM leads l 
        GROUP BY l.addeddate")
public Map<LocalDateTime, Integer> getLeadNumberByDayInDateRange();
```

or something like:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "getLeadNumberByDayInDateRange", 
query = "SELECT l.addeddate, Count(DISTINCT l.campaignid)
         FROM leads l 
         GROUP BY l.addeddate")
public Map<LocalDateTime, Integer> getLeadNumberByDayInDateRange();
```

Or if you want some custom mappings, you can use [sql result set mappings].[1](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/SqlResultSetMapping.html)

Comment: When i try this i get : Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found ',' near line 1, column 48 [SELECT l.addeddate, Count(DISTINCT l.campaignid, l.email) as count FROM leads l GROUP BY l.addeddate]. Can you help me do that in xml ?

Comment: well i need unique combination of those 2 values so i have to give it 2 params